# Android Custom Icon ShareActionProvider?

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

i'm using a ShareActionProvider, but i want to custom the icon (i want to change the color, because currently, it's white).

I'm using this code :

```
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    myIntent.setType("text/plain");
    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, str_share);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
```

The XML :

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
  android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
  android:title="@string/titlePartager"
  android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"/>
```

How can i change the icon (or color) ?

thx,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit / Short answer:** if using AppCompat's ShareActionProvider, just provide a new [`actionModeShareDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#actionModeShareDrawable) in your theme definition.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/my_share_drawable</item>
</style>
```

If *not* using AppCompat, then [this resource is defined for Lollipor or newer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionModeShareDrawable), but not for previous versions.

---

*Below is answer for the native `ShareActionProvider` (which was the original scope of this question).*

To change this image, you should change the value of `actionModeShareDrawable` for your app's theme. Take a look at the `ShareActionProvider`'s `onCreateActionView()` method:

```
public View onCreateActionView() {
    // Create the view and set its data model.
    ...

    // Lookup and set the expand action icon.
    TypedValue outTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionModeShareDrawable, outTypedValue, true);
    Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(outTypedValue.resourceId);
    ...
```

Unfortunately this attribute is *not* public in the Android framework (though it *is* if using compatibility libraries, such as AppCompat or ActionBarSherlock). In that case, it's just a matter of overriding that value for the theme.

If you are using neither of these libraries, the only solution (that I know of) is to create a subclass of `ShareActionProvider` and reimplement the `onCreateActionView()` method. You can then use whatever drawable you want instead.

**EDIT** However this is further complicated by the fact that the implementation of `onCreateActionView()` uses other classes that are not public either. To avoid duplicating a lot of code, you can just change the icon via reflection, like this:

```
public class MyShareActionProvider extends ShareActionProvider
{
    private final Context mContext;

    public MyShareActionProvider(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView()
    {
        View view = super.onCreateActionView();
        if (view != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Drawable icon = ... // the drawable you want (you can use mContext to get it from resources)
                Method method = view.getClass().getMethod("setExpandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable", Drawable.class);
                method.invoke(view, icon);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("MyShareActionProvider", "onCreateActionView", e);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

As with any solutions that involve reflection, this may be brittle if the internal implementation of `ShareActionProvider` changes in the future.

Comment: mhhh, i don't understand how to reimplement the oncreateactionview, what's the initial code in this function ?

Comment: @devLost The original code is at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.java Are you _sure_ you're not using the `appcompat` library? Because if you did, it would be way easier, this approach involves duplicating a lot of framework code.

Comment: mhh, i tried to modify this code, to change the drawable, but i had many errors. I will try again. What will change if i import the appcompat library ?

Comment: @deveLost Yes, because it uses other classes that are private to the framework too. You will have to duplicate those classes too :/

Comment: @deveLost Edited my answer with a possibly better solution.

Comment: i tried that :
        mShareActionProvider = (MyShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, str_share);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
        

        but i've a nullpointerexception, i don't know where :/

Comment: @deveLost Strange, I used this in a test project with no problems at all. You did change the menu xml to use `com.your.package.name.MyShareActionProvider`, right? If you post the stack trace from logcat we might be able to diagnose it.

Comment: yes, i did it. Ok, i check again, and i share it here if i've the problem again. thx for help :)

Comment: oh it's running, nice man ! (just a little mistake from myself) Thx a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

To change the icon for the ShareActionProvider you need to extend the AppCompat theme and set your custom icon to "actionModeShareDrawable":

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_share</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now you need to  set `"MyTheme"` as theme for `application / activity.`

Comment: I don't want to change the background color :/

Comment: the Sherlock theme uses the "actionModeShareDrawable" as found in theme.xml  file.

Try changing your theme to include the "actionModeShareDrawable" item directly.

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
</style>

Comment: sorry, i absolutely forgot to answer. I'm not using Sherlock, i'm using HOlo them, and that it doesn't work.